# Изображение не передвигается по нажатию клавиш

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, key

начал делать простую *2D* игру в *pycharm* и суть проблемы в том, что нажатия на клавиши в игре не работают.

Прошу помощи!

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((1600, 900))
pygame.display.set_caption("Игра приколистов")

player = pygame.image.load("D:\Файлы для питона\player1.png")
bg = pygame.image.load("D:\Файлы для питона\eackground1.jpg")

x = 50
y = 50
speed = 5

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while(run):
    clock.tick(30)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        x -= speed
    elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
        x += speed
    elif keys[pygame.K_w]:
        y -= speed
    elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
        y += speed

    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    win.blit(player, (50, 50))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: почему вы думаете что не работают ?  Х и Y у вас больше нигде не используются. и даже принта нет чтоб увидеть изменения.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все получилось, сейчас буду пытаться понять в чем было дело

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 427))
pygame.display.set_caption("Игра приколистов")

player = pygame.image.load("Ok.png")
bg = pygame.image.load("boy.jpg")

x = 50
y = 50
speed = 5

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while(run):
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    clock.tick(30)
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        x -= speed
    elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
        x += speed
    elif keys[pygame.K_w]:
        y -= speed
    elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
        y += speed


    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    win.blit(player, (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]